# Error occurred when request service 'AddModule'

Tags: dotnetnuke

After upgrading to DNN 9, I get the following error when I try to place modules on the page:

> `Error occurred when request service 'AddModule'.

[image: Error occured when request service AddModule]

With most of my modules, if I refresh the page after getting the error, the module appears "hovering" and ready to be placed on the page. But with one custom module I created using [Christoc's custom module templates](https://www.christoc.com/Products/DNN-Development-Templates), nothing happens when I refresh so it's impossible to place the module on a page.

What can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while. But I had a similar problem. In my case the problem was an extra entry in the `<moduleDefinitions>` node of the `.dnn` file. Like a reference to an ascx file that was part of the original template, but was deleted by me, but not from the .dnn file.

It seems DNN 9 is much more strict when it comes to modules and adding them.

Comment: There are no extra nodes. I made sure the the only node I touched in there was for the one ascx file I deleted from the original template. Also, it's throwing the error for all modules, even the DDN default modules like HTML.

Comment: Also, the module works just fine on my local dnndev.me site, which I just spun up with a fresh DNN install.

Comment: Then you have a different issue. Sorry I could not be of help.